# What is the Chinese lady in this 5-second video clip saying?

Tags: mandarin, simplified-characters, traditional-characters, phrase-request

https://streamable.com/e/n5fhft?autoplay=1

I finally cut it out, uploaded and asked about it after wondering about it for years. What is she saying?

Comment: Hi! Could you please tell us what you have attempted so far? The last three words are English (`firework and firecracker`); along with the context, you should be able to give a basic attempt at translation.

Answer (score 1):

"We weren't able to buy the firework and firecracker"

我们没有买到那个firework and firecracker